# How to set the id and class name of a <DIV>?

Tags: jquery, html

Mine is a simple enough question but i tried different ways they did work out.. I have following code . I am creating new `<div>` and trying to give it a class name **test**.So when i click on this `<div>` with class test i am trying to rise alert... Please help me i ma lost....

```
$('.item').click(function(){
        if(!isFullscreen){ // MAXIMIZATION
            $boxes = $(this).css('width','100%');
            $boxes.addClass("test");
            //$boxes.id = "test"; 
            $('#content').prepend( $boxes ).masonry( 'reload' );
        }
});

$(".test").click(function(){
    alert("Test");

});
```

I even tried below code: but they did not work

```
        //$boxes.className="test";
        //jQuery($boxes).attr("id","test");
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: thanks for the answers guys.... i was able to select only one ,if not i would have ticked all the three answers... thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should delegate the event:

```
$("#content").on('click', '.test', function() {
    alert("Test");
});
```

For adding an ID to the clicked element you can code:

```
this.id = 'test';
```

Note that if you add the same ID to several elements, your document becomes invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the div to the body...you should probably do this:

```
$(body).append('<div id="test" class="test">');
$boxes = $('#test');
```

And you need to delegate your click function using `on()`

change `$(".test").click(function(){` to `$('body').on('click', '.test', function(){`

Answer (score 2):

Your first function will create an element that is a member of the class `test` when an element of the class `item` is clicked on.

Your section function will add a click handler to all the members of the class `test` when it is run … which is **before** any `item` elements will have been clicked on.

Use the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/), not the `click` method and create a *Delegated event* event (see the documentation for on for instructions).